# Punch action in unreal engine, blueprint tutorial

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Sorry for the crudely formulated question but can anyone recommend a good tutorial that helps achieve this. I'm working on a 2D game using Paper2D in Unreal and found some tutorials for 3D animations in blueprint but not for the Flipbook implementation. I was trying to rig the existing animation state machine in the template paper2d character to add a "punch" state but have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a quickly searched in my bookmarks and I have found these tutorials, that I hope, they might be useful for your necessities.

Basic animation for a environment obstacle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lC4JGl1uU0I

Unreal Engine 4 Paper2D Advanced Flipbook Animation Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTRCe2wdfN4

Player controller and player character.

http://nerd-time.com/ue4-2d-platformer-player-controller/

I wish you the best of lucky in your project.